# Displaying textarea data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using XAMPP, phpmyadmin and even after correcting it so many times, in output it only shows updated records. The data is not being inserted somehow.

```
<?php 

$name=$_POST['comment']; 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','' ); 
mysql_select_db('comments',$link);
mysql_query("insert into comment values('$name'"); 
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 

<!-- window.location = "display1.php" --> </script>'; 

?>
```

**display1.php**

```
<?php 

$link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','' ); 
mysql_select_db('comments',$link); 
echo "Updated records:<br>"; 

$result=mysql_query("select * from comment"); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tempname=$row['commenting']; echo $tempname."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please retry you question, actualy nobody is able to understand this

Comment: Please reformat your code and explain your question further...

Comment: please format it again and show us a form tag

Comment: you must have to add column name in insert query... mysql_query("insert into comment(column_name) values('$name'");

Comment: no data is being displayed eventually in display1.php. Empty field values are created in the table even after inserting values from the textarea form.

Comment: Are you getting any mysql errors? Your insert code seem wrong, you dont set the comment column name. See insert syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: also insert query syntax is wrong... right syntax is....mysql_query("insert into comment(comment_column) values('$name')");

Comment: Doesn't work prince...still the same result!

Comment: try this syntax...mysql_query("insert into comment(comment_column) values('$name')");

Comment: <div id="panel"><form action="formsubmit.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="20">Enter</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</div>
this is my form

Comment: form is okay. now replace your syntax with new one which i have post

Comment: You should be getting some errors if the code dont work. Turn on error reporting unless you have it on and post us your errors!!

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. SQL injection is [very easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868). Consider [switching to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax error in your code while inserting records,

correct code is...

```
mysql_query("insert into comment(comment_column) values('$name')");
```

also redirect your page using `php header function` don't use `javascipt window.location`

replace you JavaScript code with...

```
header("Location:display1.php");
```

the whole code is...

```
<?php 

$name=$_POST['comment']; 
$link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','' ); 
mysql_select_db('comments',$link);
mysql_query("insert into comment(comment_column) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."')");
header("Location:display1.php"); 

?>
```

Comment: $name=$_POST['comment'];
$link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','' );
mysql_select_db('comments',$link);
mysql_query("insert into comment('commenting') values('$name'");
header("Location:display1.php"); 
?> still doesn't work

Comment: check i have posted whole code... you just update comment_column with your table column where the comment is store

Comment: also one more thing if your comment have characters like (' ") so you need to add mysql_real_escape_string function

Answer (score 0):

Your insert code need to have the column set

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment ('commenting') VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."')");
```

I have added a little better escape method for your query but preferrably not use mysql_* functions. PDO is more secure.